# Three.js Render Depth to Texture

Tags: three.js, depth-buffer, render-to-texture

I'm having a large number of meshes in threejs. In order to render them efficiently I merge them by materials. However, I want to select them with mouse.

My approach is the following: In one rendering pass I bake the merged meshed into a texture and in a second pass I render only the highlighted as a transparent overlay. So far, it almost works except for wrong visibility. The problem is that as I use [WebGLRenderTarget](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/WebGLRenderTarget) it stores only the FBO into the texture. I would actually need a second texture to fetch DepthBuffer, ideally without a third rendering pass. I did not find anything related in the Three.js documentation. Any ideas?

Comment: look at http://threejs.org/examples/js/postprocessing/BokehPass.js for example, they have this.scene.overrideMaterial = this.materialDepth; renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera, this.renderTargetDepth, true );

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of the `overrideMaterial`. Their solution didn't work for me. The color texture was fine, but the depth texture contained nothing. So I ended up by substituting the depth pass with a normal rendering pass and clearing the color afterwards. However, it is a 3-passes solution. I would prefer 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to think differently. You cannot use a depth texture to write into the depth buffer. The only way to write into the depth buffer is to render primitives.

How about this:

- Bake your scene into a texture but render depth into the on-screen depth buffer.
- Keep the depth buffer in the second pass
- Render your baked texture with depth tests and depth writes disabled: `gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); gl.depthMask(false);`
- Render your selected object(s) with the highlight material

Comment: Exactly, that is what I described in my previous comments to the question. It is a solution, but not very flexible. I know I can't write to the depth buffer from a texture, but I could perform the depth test in a fragment shader instead. So my question is - how to store not only the color, but also the depth (in e.g. to alpha) using a rendertarget in three.js?

Comment: If you're happy to do you own depth test in a shader, you can render into a depth texture. This is not yet merged into three.js proper, but take a look at this pull request (it also includes a demo): https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/5402

Comment: I will try to avoid messing up with unpulled extensions. But I hope it will arrive to the repo soon :)